# sort and uniq commands not running as expected when run though cron

Tags: cron, sort, uniq, case-sensitivity

Below is a part of script which gives proper output when run manually
but gives incorrect output when run using cron:

```
sort < file1.out | uniq -ic |sort -nr> file2.out
```

When run on the command line, this gives a count where lines are
grouped ignoring case, such as:

```
73 /universal/webselfservice/pdf/r60.pdf
```

When running through cron, the counts are split when case varies, for
example:

```
47 /universal/webselfservice/pdf/r60.pdf
26 /universal/webselfservice/pdf/R60.pdf
```

How can I get the cron output to match the command line behavior?

Comment: could be because you need to give the explicit path to the input and output files for the cron job. or try specifying `sort -f`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The locale used under cron is different to that in your interactive environment.  One has case case-insensitive collation, and the other does not.

This means that interactively, the first `sort` puts `/universal/webselfservice/pdf/r60.pdf` and `/universal/webselfservice/pdf/R60.pdf` adjacent, so `uniq -i` can combine them.  But in the locale used by cron, they are not adjacent, and get counted separately.

There two simple means to get what you want:

1. specify your case-insensitive locale as an environment variable in your crontab file, or
2. add `-f` (or `--ignore-case`) flag to the first `sort`.